# how to set a parameter of a json object inside a json array in ember

Tags: json, ember.js

I need to access and change the a boolean parameter 'SELECTED' of a json object inside a json array using ember set method, but when i tried it I got error message "Assertion Failed: Cannot call set with 'false' key".
Also tried to access the data using a temp Object.

structure of JSON Array:

```
[
    {
        "VALUE":
            [
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_added",
                    "NAME":"ADDED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_deleted",
                    "NAME":"DELETED"
                },
                {   "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_disabled",
                    "NAME":"DISABLED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_enabled",
                    "NAME":"ENABLED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_modified",
                    "NAME":"MODIFIED"
                }
            ],
            "KEY":"",
            "NAME":"",
                            "SELECTED":false
    },
    {   
        "VALUE":
            [
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_deleted",
                    "NAME":"DELETED"
                }
            ],
        "KEY":"",
        "NAME":"",
                    "SELECTED":false
    },
    {
        "VALUE":
            [
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_added",
                    "NAME":"ADDED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_deleted",
                    "NAME":"DELETED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_disabled",
                    "NAME":"DISABLED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_enabled",
                    "NAME":"ENABLED"
                },
                {
                    "SELECTED":false,
                    "KEY":"audit_actions_updated",
                    "NAME":"UPDATED"
                }
            ],
        "KEY":"",
        "NAME":"",
                    "SELECTED":false
    }
]
```

I can get the values but can't change those in ember.

**Answer:**

I solved it, the problem was I tried to set a parameter of a JSON Object of a JSON Array using ember set method, which in ember by default takes the value of parameter not the key, to overcome the issue I started using JSON Array.replace method of ember by making a copy of the JSON Object and changing the parameter which I need to change and replace the JSON Object itself in the JSON Array. Now it works fine.

Comment: It sounds like the parameters you are passing to `set` are in the wrong order. Try switching positions between 'SELECTED' and false

Comment: If this is not the issue, you should provide more information about the piece of code in which you are calling `set` on the array.

Comment: Thanks Henry, I solved it, the problem was I tried to set a parameter of a JSON Object of a JSON Array, which in ember by default takes the value of parameter not the key, to overcome the issue I started using JSON Array.replace method of ember by making a copy of the JSON Object and changing the parameter which I need to change and replace the JSON Object itself in the JSON Array. Now it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, the problem was I tried to set a parameter of a JSON Object of a JSON Array using ember set method, which in ember by default takes the value of parameter not the key, to overcome the issue I started using JSON Array.replace method of ember by making a copy of the JSON Object and changing the parameter which I need to change and replace the JSON Object itself in the JSON Array. Now it works fine.